# Как правильно: высылаем двадцать три дипломата, или высылаем двадцать трёх дипломатов?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, числительные

Как правильно: *высылаем двадцать три дипломата* или *высылаем двадцать трёх дипломатов*?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если в конце числа имеется **единица** (1, 21, 31, 91 и т. д.; кроме 11), то существительные мужского рода, оканчивающиеся на согласную или **-ь**, если неодушевлены, принимают форму именительного падежа, а если одушевлены, — родительного:

высылаем (что?) один платок, высылаем двадцать один платок;
***высылаем (кого?) одного дипломата, высылаем двадцать одного дипломата.***

2. Если число **в точности равно двум, трем или четырем**, то конструкция с неодушевленным существительным принимает форму именительного падежа:
   высылаем (что?) три платка.

Конструкция же с одушевленным существительным — форму родительного падежа:
***высылаем (кого?) трех дипломатов.***

3. Если число, оканчивающееся на 2, 3 или 4 (22, 23, 24, 52, 53, 54 и т. д., но не на 12, 13, 14), является многозначным, то винительный падеж совпадает с именительным как для конструкций с одушевленными, так и для конструкций с неодушевленными существительными:
   высылаем (что?) двадцать три платка;
   ***высылаем (кого?) двадцать три дипломата.***

[**Числительное + существительное в винительном падеже**](http://nekin.info/math/imya_chislitelnoye.htm)

Comment: Несколько замечаний по ответу: 1) Мне кажется, что сначала нужно чётко ответить на заданный вопрос, а потом уж комментировать свой ответ и приводить правила (а не наоборот).   2) Не имеет смысла излагать ту часть правил, которая к данному вопросу отношения не имеет. Иначе это будет ответ не на заданный вопрос,  а на вопрос, как в общем случае обозначается категория одушевленности. 3) Ссылка дана на недостаточно авторитетный источник, при этом   информация из правил Розенталя не учитывается и не упоминается  вообще.

Comment: Я преклоняюсь перед Вашими **глобальными** знаниями, и обычно после Ваших ответов я со своими уже не суюсь. Но мне этот Ваш ответ показался не совсем точным (несмотря на ссылку на Розенталя). Вы пишете: _в конструкциях с составными числительными, оканчивающимися на два, три, четыре, винительный падеж сохраняет форму именительного независимо от категории одушевлённости._ А это не так. Числа 12, 13, 14, 112, 113, 114 и т. д. в этот кусочек правила не входят: высылаем тринадцать дипломатов. Поэтому я и дала такой обширный ответ. Вы считаете его неправильным?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не обижайтесь, нас (постоянно отвечающих на вопросы) так мало, и всех ценишь, как ХОРОШИХ ДРУЗЕЙ. И нет никаких глобальных знаний, мы здесь все одинаковые,  так как  любое суждение должны  подтверждать цитатами из классиков. И теперь по существу:  тринадцать - это сложное, а не составное числительное, оно категорию одушевленности не выражает и стоит в В.п. А число сто двенадцать не включает числительные два, три, четыре, которые могут выражать одушевленность, поэтому с ним тоже нет проблем.

Answer (score 3):

Нейтральный стиль: **высылаем двадцать три дипломата**, разговорная форма: **высылаем двадцать трёх дипломатов**.

http://www.rosental-book.ru/styli_xxxvi.html#sect151.3

При нормальной форме доставить **двадцать два пассажира** (в конструкциях с составными числительными, оканчивающимися на два, три, четыре, винительный падеж сохраняет форму именительного независимо от категории одушевленности) существует разговорная форма доставить **двадцать двух пассажиров.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Откуда берется проблема с этим числительным?**

По правилам составное числительное одушевленность не выражает и должно стоять в форме И.п. Но  числительное ***двадцать три*** включает числительное ***двадцать***, которое не выражает одушевленность, и числительное ***три***, которое может выражать  одушевленность. Поэтому появляется желание **разделить составное числительное на части с разными формами падежей,** но такое деление допускается только в разговорной речи.

**Грамматическая справка**

1)  Ряд числительных (ДВА, ТРИ, ЧЕТЫРЕ И СОБИРАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫЕ) могут выражать категорию одушевленности-неодушевленности при сочетании с существительными:

А) для одушевленных сущ.  форма В.п. совпадает с формой Р.п.: встретил  (кого?) двух девушек, двух студентов, обоих всадников.

Б) для неодушевленных сущ. форма В.п. совпадает с формой И.п.: 
прочитал (что?) две книги, отдыхал двое суток, купил оба стола .

2) Неопределенно-количественные существительные выражают одушевленность/неодушевленность непоследовательно: знать несколько (нескольких) человек – используются оба варианта.